# Configuring a currency converter to get exchange rate feeds for for multiple currencies

Tags: php, xml, url, configuration, rss

I'm trying to make my function more versatile by removing hard coded data.

```
function get_currency_rate($currencySource) {

if (isset($currencySource)) {
        $feed = $currencySource;
    } else {
        echo 'Feed not found.  Check URL';
    }

    if (!$feed) {
        echo('Feed not found');
    }


    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

    $rate = get_rate($xml, 15); //EUR
    if ($feed == 'http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/USD/rss.xml') {
        $rate = get_rate($xml, 16); //GBP
    } else {
        $rate = get_rate($xml, 56);  //USD
    }
}
```

I would prefer to pass in the values `15`, `16`, `56` and the URL `'http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/USD/rss.xml'` rather than hard coding them into the function.

Below is the `get_rate` function.

```
// Get and return currency rate
// Perform regular exp<b></b>ression to extrat numeric data
// Split title string to extract currency title 
function get_rate(SimpleXMLElement $xml, $xmlTagPosition) {

    $currency['rate'] = $xml->channel->item[$xmlTagPosition]->description;
    preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $currency['rate'], $matches);
    $rate = $matches[0];

    $title['rate'] = $xml->channel->item[$xmlTagPosition]->title;
    $title = explode('/', $title['rate']);
    $title = $title[0];

    echo $rate . ' ' . $title . '<br />';
}
```

The feed URLs are set in my `cityConfig.php` script as below:

```
// Feed URLs //
$theMoneyConverter = 'http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/';

// Define arrays // 
$cities = array('London', 'New York', 'Paris');
$currencyHeadings = array('London - 1 British Pound Sterling', 'New York - 1 US Dollar', 'Paris - 1 Euro');
$currencySource = array($theMoneyConverter . 'GBP/rss.xml', $theMoneyConverter . 'USD/rss.xml', $theMoneyConverter . 'EUR/rss.xml');
$currencyId = array(15, 16, 56); 
?>
```

Notice the `$currencyId` array values are the same as those hard coded into the `get_currency_rate` function. I tried passing in a second parameter for the `$currencyId` to no avail. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

I have tried the following:

Added an argument onto the end of the feed URL's e.g.

```
?x=15 // for EURO feed
?x=16 // for GBP feed
?x=56 // for USD feed
```

These numbers correspond to the position of the  XML tag as an array from the feed URL's.

```
$currencySource = array($theMoneyConverter . 'GBP/rss.xml?x=15', $theMoneyConverter . 'USD/rss.xml?x=16', $theMoneyConverter . 'EUR/rss.xml?x=56');
```

I have edited the get_rate function to parse in the URL and the PHP query.

```
// Get and return currency rate
// Perform regular expression to extrat numeric data
// Split title string to extract currency title 
function get_rate(SimpleXMLElement $xml) {

    $vars = parse_url($xml, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($vars);
    echo "x = " . $x;
    //$x = 15; 

    $currency['rate'] = $xml->channel->item[$x]->description;
    preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $currency['rate'], $matches);
    $rate = $matches[0];

    $title['rate'] = $xml->channel->item[$x]->title;
    $title = explode('/', $title['rate']);
    $title = $title[0];

    echo $rate . ' ' . $title . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing I notice is that your `get_currency_rate()` function requires a `$currencySource` to be added as a parameter. Which makes the first if statement a little redundant. The other thing is that `get_currency_rate()` is setting the variable `$rate` from `get_rate()`, but `get_rate()` doen't return anything.

I think you should ommit the `get_currency_rate()` function and change `get_rate()` to handle the XML feed request and return the information you want rather than using two separate functions.

It would look like this.

```
function get_rate($feed_url, $xmlTagPosition) {
  $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed_url);
  $xml_item = $xml->channel->item[$xmlTagPosition];

  // make sure the $xmlTagPosition was valid
  if( empty($xml_item) )
    return false;

  $currency['rate'] = $xml_item->description;
  preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $currency['rate'], $matches);
  $rate = $matches[0];

  $title['rate'] = $xml_item->title;
  $title = explode('/', $title['rate']);
  $title = $title[0];

  return $rate . ' ' . $title;
}
```

And now your `cityConfig.php` file can work more like this.

```
$theMoneyConverter = 'http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/USD/rss.xml';

$cities = array(
  'London' => array(
    'title' => '1 British Pound Sterling',
    'currency_id' => 15
  ),
  'New York' => array(
    'title' => '1 US Dollar',
    'currency_id' => 16
  ),
  'Paris' => array(
    'title' => '1 Euro',
    'currency_id' => 56
  )
);

// now you can easily find and loop through each of your cities
foreach( $cities as $city => $info ) {
  echo '<p>';
  echo "$city - {$info['title']}";
  echo get_rate($theMoneyConverter, $info['currency_id']);
  echo '</p>';
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into using a direct API for currency conversion (http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/) That way you don't have to worry about the xml tag position changing.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by introducing a few variables, and a sub to set them.

```
function set_values(&$initial, &$matched, &$unmatched, &$matchFeed){
  $initial =15;  //eur
  $matched=16;   //GBP
  $unmatched=56; //USD
  $matchFeed = "http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/USD/rss.xml";

}

function get_currency_rate($currencySource) {
    if (isset($currencySource)) {
        $feed = $currencySource;
    } else {
        echo 'Feed not found.  Check URL';
    }

    if (!$feed) {
        echo('Feed not found');
    }

    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

    set_values($initital, $matched, $unmatched, $matchFeed);

    $rate = get_rate($xml, $initial);
    if ($feed == $matchFeed) {
        $rate = get_rate($xml, $matched);
    } else {
        $rate = get_rate($xml, $unmatched);
    }
}
```

Now you are ready to get the values from wherever you want to, without changing the primary function.

Once that is done, you might want to take a look at the config.php file.

```
$currencyIds= array(15, 16, 56); 
$currencySource = array($theMoneyConverter . 'GBP/rss.xml', $theMoneyConverter . 'USD/rss.xml', $theMoneyConverter . 'EUR/rss.xml', $currencyIds );
```

Creates an array wih 3 strings and one array of three integers(four total). Depending upon your usage, that might be what you want.

?>